# wsse_auth_callback don't work in wash_out soap service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, wash-out

Why [wash_out](https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out) (0.9.0) don't work with :wsse_auth_callback in parameters?

I used this initialization code:

```
soap_service :namespace => 'urn:SoapService', wsse_auth_callback: ->(username, password){
    ...
}
```

And I got this error:

> The following keys are not allows: [:wsse_auth_callback] Did you intend for one of the following? [:parser, :namespace, :wsdl_style, :snakecase_input, :camelize_wsdl, :catch_xml_errors, :wsse_username, :wsse_password]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently only available to the version from git master. We didn't release any public versions with this new feature yet.

Comment: Do you have any plan to release the public version of wsse_auth_callback feature? Thank you for your awesome gem. It's really helping a lot so far.